# Consultas a base de datos con Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy en un proyecto con Django y necesito hacer lo siguiente:

-Necesito obtener mediante consultas ciertos campos de mi modelo, utilizando Django.

modelo:

```
class Tickets(model.Model):

    title = model.Charfield()
    description = model.Charfield()
    postal_code = model.Charfield()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Titulo: " + self.title + " Descripcion " + self.description + " Codigo postal" + self.postal_code
```

Esto es un ejemplo de la consulta que quiero hacer :

```
SELECT title FROM Tickets;
SELECT postal_code FROM Tickets WHERE id=10;
```

-He intentado hacerlo usando las consultas raw() y con consultas normales utilizando los metodos filter() y demas, pero cada vez que realizo una consulta me devuelve un objeto Query el cual si imprimo me devuelve:

```
Titulo : "el titulo" Descripcion: "Descripcion" Codigo postal : "El codigo postal"  

#Esto es lo que se definio en la funcion __str__ de mi modelo
```

-Y mi objetivo es conseguir el valor de un campo concreto

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como

```py
    tickets = Ticket.objects.values_list('title')

    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(id=10).values_list('postal_code')
```

Y luego quizas

```py
for ticket in tickets:
    print (f"Titulo: {ticket.title}")
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo, muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, era lo que estaba buscando!!